# Помогите решить с перебором

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

```
#! usr/bin python3

import csv
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return response.read()


f = open('text.txt', 'r')
l = [line.strip() for line in f]

def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    search = soup.find('div', class_='search-total js-search-total')
    span = soup.find('span', class_='search-message js-page-title')
    spantext = span.text
    searchtext = search.text

    save (searchtext, spantext, 'project.csv')

def save(searchtext, spantext, path):
    with open(path, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(('Название', 'Кол-во'))
        for row in l:
            writer.writerow((spantext, searchtext))
        csvfile.close()


def main():
    for url in l:
        parse(get_html(url))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

В project.csv в итоге получается 2 строчки с одинаковыми данными, хотя урлы в text.txt разные , и данные , соответственно, тоже разные.

Куда посоветуете обратить внимание ?

Comment: `for url in l: parse(get_html(url))`?

Comment: @kff, пишите ответ.

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik, я так понимаю, csv прочитать так и не удалось? Вы хот реагируйте на комментарии.

Comment: проблему с кодировкой так и не решил, и понял, что намного проще решается чтением .txt

Comment: @kff не понял :)

Comment: если я пишу так:

def main():
    for url in l:
        parse(get_html(url))

то консоль выдаёт:
    spantext = span.text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik, значит строчка `span = soup.find('span', class_='search-message js-page-title')` отдает Вам `None`. Т.е. BS не может найти span с таким классом. Смотрите, что у Вас в `url`, если все ОК, смотрите, что отдает `get_html`, если все ОК, попробуйте вывести `soup.prettify()`

Comment: @andy, всё верно, не по всем урлам были эти классы, 
а я почему-то и не перепроверил ...

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik не создавайте копии вопросов